# How to close a Dialog with radio buttons by clicking on a radiobutton

Tags: android, dialog, radio-button

It feels like a very stupid question but i cant figure out how to close my dialog when the user clicks a radiobutton in the dialog.. (so something like alert.dismiss() in the onClick)

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Nederland", "België", "Denemarken", "Duitsland", "Frankrijk", "Italië", "Luxemburg", "Oostenrijk", "Verenigd Koningkrijg", "Zweden"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Selecteer het land");
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                Button country = (Button) findViewById(R.id.land_fac_but);
                country.setText(items[item]);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();   
        alert.show();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add `dialog.dismiss()` inside your `OnClickListener`:

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    Button country = (Button) findViewById(R.id.land_fac_but);
    country.setText(items[item]);
    dialog.dismiss();
  }
});
```

If you want to dismiss it as soon as an item is clicked. Else you might want to look into creating a more custom `Dialog` by extending `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `dialog.dismiss()` in the `onClick()` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try below apis:

```
cancel
dismiss
```

Your code will look like:

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            Button country = (Button) findViewById(R.id.land_fac_but);
            country.setText(items[item]);
            dialog.cancel();
        }
```

There is slight diff between two, check this out:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#cancel()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss()

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Selecteer het land");  
        final AlertDialog alert;  
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                Button country = (Button) findViewById(R.id.land_fac_but);
                country.setText(items[item]);
                alert.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alert = builder.create();   
        alert.show();
```